# Tailwind custom classes aren't applied for mobile devices and Chrome DevTools, but work on desktop and Safari DevTools

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I use Tailwind CSS for my project and I was developing for desktop, with RWD working on Safari and Google Chrome.
However, when I switched to use the DevTools it just doesn't work.
I'm having the same issue using a mobile device.

For example on a mobile device (iphone7+) only `h-vh70` is applied.

```
<div class="h-vh30 sm:h-vh50 md:h-vh70 w-screen flex justify-center items-end">
        <img src="./src/img/banner 1.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

My `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    //my html files
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
    height: {
        vh30: "30vh",
        vh50: "50vh",      
        vh70: "70vh",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-textshadow"), require("autoprefixer")],
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i forgot to add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

problem solved!